# JMeter maven plugin - Customize reportgenerator.properties

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

When I'm using the JMeter Maven plugin, and running `mvn jmeter:configure` it automatically creates a default `bin/reportgenerator.properties` file.

How can I customize this file? Is there a way to specify some of the properties in the jmeter-maven plugin configuration so that I can set, for example, `report_title`?

See: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Modifying Properties](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties) chapter of JMeter Maven Plugin [wiki](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/).

You need to add the following block to your `<plugin>` section:

```
<configuration>
    <propertiesUser>
        <jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>your-custom-title</jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>
    </propertiesUser>
</configuration>
```

Full pom.xml just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>your-custom-title</jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>
                    </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

Add to [pom.xml](https://sarkershantonu.github.io/2020/09/04/maven-jmeter-reporting/)

> ```
> <jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>Shantonu Example</jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>
> ```

Comment: yep works. thanks.